Insert MergeFields, one per row inside a table cell in Word VBA withou using Select and Selection
I want to put some data as MergeFields, one per row inside a single cell in a table, without using Select and Selection.
I tried many things, even ones sugested by ChatGPT that had some sense in it and they did not work.
Note: I will skip variable declarations just to go to the point.
For example:
    With doc.MailMerge.Fields
        Set ultCar = t.Cell(1, 1).Range
        ultCar.Text = ""
        Set para = ultCar.Paragraphs.Add
        .Add para.Range.Characters.Last, "FirstName"
        para.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf
        .Add para.Range.Characters.Last, "LastName"
End With

Another example made by ChatGPT:
Sub InsertMailMergeFieldsInSeparateRows()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim cellRange As Range

    ' Asignar el documento activo
    Set doc = ActiveDocument

    ' Crear una tabla de 2x2 en el documento
    Set tbl = doc.Tables.Add(Range:=doc.Range(0, 0), NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=2)
    tbl.Borders.Enable = True

    ' Obtener el rango de la celda donde se insertarán los campos
    Set cellRange = tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range
    cellRange.Text = "" ' Limpiar contenido inicial

    ' Insertar los campos de combinar correspondencia en filas separadas
    With doc.MailMerge.Fields
        ' Insertar el primer campo
        .Add Range:=cellRange, Name:="FirstName"
        
        ' Agregar un salto de párrafo
        cellRange.InsertAfter vbCr
        
        ' Insertar el segundo campo en la siguiente fila
        Set cellRange = tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range
        cellRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Add Range:=cellRange, Name:="LastName"
    End With
End Sub

Either examples wont work. I don't want to use Select or Selection and I'm trying to learn to write alternative code to avoid this AMAP.
I wrote code previously using Select and Selection that works but document takes seconds to generate and I read that working on ranges etc directly is more eficient and safer.

Why are you trying to do this in code instead of automating a mailmerge main document already configured with all the required fields etc.?

@macropod Yes, i know I can do a template with all already inserted probably but I am doing it for the sake of learning to manipulate things in a document, cause Word VBA behaves a bit weirdly to me compared to excel.

Your script is close to finish. Pls try
Sub Demo()
    Dim doc As Document, t As Table, rngDes As Range
    Dim para As Paragraph, rngCell As Range
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set t = doc.Tables(1)
    With doc.MailMerge.Fields
        Set rngCell = t.Cell(1, 1).Range
        rngCell.Text = ""
        .Add rngCell, "FirstName"
        Set para = rngCell.Paragraphs.Add
        Set rngDes = para.Range.Duplicate
        rngDes.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
        .Add rngDes, "LastName"
    End With
End Sub



Your code inserts paragraph breaks between the mergefields, not the line breaks shown in your answer.

I found a very simple way. Just adding fields in reverse order from last to first and doing a rng.insertBefore vbCr between each .add. As simple as that. Very clean way I think. I just thought of it after trying your result which worked, but I asked ChatGPT how .add added a MergeField inside a range, what the behaviour was and how it affected the field and it said fields are added at the beginning of a range so I thought doing it in reverse should work and it did.

ChatGPT is very unreliable when it comes to programming; it often just makes things up. Its use here was banned for some time.

@macropod it’s still banned

That simply isn't true.  Your screenshot clearly shows line breaks whereas you code says to output paragraph breaks - which is exactly what it does. I tested it.

@macropod I haven't seen the requirment of line breaks in OP. I think paragraph break works.

@macropod https://i.sstatic.net/pomHvifg.gif  I knew you are a Word expert. Here comes a gif about my testing.  Would you please let me know what's wrong with it?

This isn't about what the OP required but concerns the fact that your screenshot doesn't match what you say your code does.

I don't think so. The gif shows the output.

not the line breaks shown in your answer - The term line break does not appear in either my script or my answer.

I found the way of doing it, in reserse order, starting from the last field to the first, inserting a new line between each one with .insertBefore vbNewLine.
Sub Demo()
    Dim doc As Document, t As Table
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set t = doc.Tables(1)
    With doc.MailMerge.Fields
        Set rngCell = t.Cell(1, 1).Range
        rngCell.Text = ""
        .Add rngCell, "LastName"
        rngCell.insertBefore vbNewLine
        .Add rngCell, "FirstName"

        'And so on with each field in reverse order.
    End With
End Sub


There are numerous ways you could do this. For example:
Sub Demo1()
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range
  .Collapse wdCollapseStart
  .Fields.Add .Duplicate, , "MERGEFIELD LastName", False
  .InsertBefore Chr(11)
  .Collapse wdCollapseStart
  .Fields.Add .Duplicate, , "MERGEFIELD FirstName", False
End With
End Sub

Sub Demo2()
Dim Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument
  Set Rng = .Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range
  Rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
  Rng.Text = " " & Chr(11) & " "
  .MailMerge.Fields.Add Rng.Characters.First, "FirstName"
  .MailMerge.Fields.Add Rng.Characters.Last, "LastName"
End With
End Sub

